# Does weak convergence in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R},L^p(\mathbb{R}^n))$ imply strong convergence in $L^p_{loc}(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Tags: lp-spaces, weak-convergence, bochner-spaces, strong-convergence

Does weak convergence in $L^\infty\left(\mathbb{R},L^p\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)\right)$ imply strong convergence in $L^p_{loc}\left(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n\right)$ up to a subsequence ?

Comment: what do you mean by $L^\infty(\mathbb{R},L^p(\mathbb{R}^n))$?

Comment: It is a Bochner space.